# Запрос для вывода топ-3

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица с историей посещений страниц пользователями. Необходимо вывести топ-3 страницы, которые чаще всего являются последними (по дате посещения) для пользователя

[image: tab1]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

В постановке задачи есть одна загвоздка... В последнюю секунду пользователь мог посетить несколько сайтов, что ж, возьмём любой из них...

```
SELECT url, COUNT(*)score
FROM(
  SELECT url
  FROM table
  ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
)T
GROUP BY url 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 3
```